# How should feature toggles be set in tests run in continuous integration?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, featuretoggle

How does one go about testing when using feature toggles? You want your development computer to be as close to production as possible. From videos I watched, feature toggles are implemented in a way to allow certain people to "use" the feature (i.e., 0 to 100 % of users, or selected users, etc.).

To do continuous integration correctly, would you have to use the same feature toggle settings as the production servers when it comes to testing? Or better yet, if the feature is not off on production, make sure it's on when it comes to running automated tests in the build pipeline? Do you end up putting feature toggles in your testing code, or write tests in a new file? When is the new feature a mandatory step in a process that must occur for system tests?

Comment: I would say you would have to run tests against every possible permutation of feature toggles (I assume you have have multiple features toggles) and I would definitely use same mechanics.

Comment: After doing a bit of research, Martin Fowler suggests...

`In general there's no need to test all combinations of features. For release toggles it's usually sufficient to run two combinations. 1) all the toggles on that are expected to be on in the next release. 2) all toggles on` http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html

Answer (score 7):

In a team of more than a few people that uses feature toggles routinely, it's impractical to do combinatorial testing of all toggles or even to plan testing of combinations of toggles that are expected to interact. A practical strategy for testing toggled code has to work for a single toggle without considering the states of the other toggles. I've seen the following process work fairly well:

- Because we move all code to production as soon as possible, when a toggle is initially introduced into a project, new tests are written to cover all toggled code with the toggle on. Because we test thoroughly, tests for that code with the toggle off already exist; those tests are changed so that the toggle is explicitly off. Toggled code can be developed behind the toggle as long as is necessary.
- Immediately before the toggle is turned on in production, all tests (not just the tests of the toggled code, but the application's entire test suite) are run with the toggle on. This catches any breakage due to unforeseen interactions with other features.
- The toggle is turned on in production
- The toggle is removed from the code (along with any code that is active only when the toggle is off) and the code is deployed to production

This process applies both to cases where a toggle only hides completely new functionality (so that there is no code that runs only when the toggle is off) and to cases where a toggle selects between two or more versions of the code, like a split test.

To answer a couple of your specific points:

- Whether the tests of different toggled states go in the same file or a different file depends on the size of the toggled feature. If it's a small change, it's easiest to keep both versions in the same file. If it's a complete rewrite of a major feature, it's probably easier to have one or more new test files devoted to the new state of the toggle. The number of files affected by the toggle also depends on your test architecture. For example, in a Rails project that uses RSpec and Cucumber a toggle might require new tests in Cucumber features (acceptance/integration tests), routing specs, controller specs, and model specs, and, again, tests of the toggle at each level might be in the same file or a different file depending on the size of the toggled feature.
- By "system tests" I think you mean manual tests. I prefer to not have those. Instead, I automate all tests, including acceptance tests, so what I wrote above applies to all tests. Leaving that aside, the new state of the toggle becomes law once temporarily when we run all the tests with the toggle on before turning it on in production, and then permanently when we remove the toggle.